# Cisco 3550 internal queue statistics under IOS 12.1?

Tags: cisco, switch

I am seeing slow-down in a switched network. Looking at the points where the users are reporting slow-down to/from, I have located two Cisco 3550 as the most likely points to start digging.

Normally, I would've checked the internal queues with `show platform port-asic stats`, but taht command does not seem to be available in IOS 12.1, any ideas on other things I can look at to verify if these switches are (or are not) part of where the network issues are?

`show interface` does not show any input or output drops/errors, but when we've had similar issues in the past, it's only really been evident with the ASIC stats, so I am at a bit of a loss what to check next.

*Edit*: One of the interfaces is a trunk interface (GigE, carrying 28 Mbps of traffic), the other interfaces are access ports, 100 Mbps each, none of the ports is even close to "full" (the 28 Mbps is, essentially, the aggregate of the other ports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe a very simple and horrible wrong answer, but did you check the bitrate of the connections? and the connection between these 2 switches is set to trunk i assume?

Comment: Wish it had been that easy. In the past, we've had QoS problems on this (yeah, yeah, I know, QoS and switch-based networks ain't the best in the world, but it's a pretty large network and a bit too late in the day to rip it apart and start from scratch).

Answer (score 0):

From the lack of answers here and the lack of answers on [CCO](http://www.cisco.com/), I am starting to think that what I want to check simply isn't available in this version of IOS and if I want it, I'll have to upgrade.